# In how many functions maxterm/minterm of n binary variables can be expressed

Tags: math, boolean, boolean-logic

I have confusion. Semantically we can construct 2^(2^n) boolean functions, but I read in Digital Electronics Morris Mano that we can construct 2^2n combinations of minterm/maxterm. How?

Comment: Perhaps 2^2n is a typo. It has to be if every Boolean function can be expressed in such a way. Note that `(2^2)^n = 2^2n`. Perhaps the author got momentarily sloppy in interpreting a tower of exponents.

Comment: @JohnColeman Its 2 to power 2 which has power n, its not (2^2)^n. Perhaps you got sloppy ^_^

Comment: I know what `2^2^n` is but whoever wrote it as `2^2n` might have had it confused. They seem to have mentally read it as (2^2)^n.

Answer (score 0):

Samsamp, could you point to a specific place in the book or even better provide an exact quote? In the copy I found over the Internet I was not able to find such a claim after a fast glance over. The closest thing I found is:

> Since the function can be either I or 0 for each minterm, and since there
>   are 2^n min terms, one can calculate the possible functions that can be formed with n variables to be 2^2^n.

which looks OK to me.